# How to position the legend at the bottom after adjusting plot.margin in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

In ggplot2, I would like to increase the bottom plot margin (using the `plot.margin` argument of `theme()`) and position the legend at the bottom of the plot window.

Consider the following example code:

```
library("ggplot2")

d <- data.frame(x = c(8,6,5,1,8,9,6,4),
                y = c(6,5,4,3,7,1,6,4),
                v = rep(c("a","b"), each = 4))
p <- ggplot(d, aes(x, y, colour = v)) + geom_point()
p + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,4,1), "cm"),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

which produces the following output:

[image: Plot with a large bottom margin]

As you can see, the above plot has a large bottom margin (as specified by the `plot.margin` argument in the original code). But the legend is *not* at the bottom of the plot window, despite the `legend.position` argument being set to `"bottom"`. It looks like the additional bottom margin space has been added to the plot after the legend was put at the bottom... I want to do it the other way around (i.e. increase the bottom margin and *then* put the legend at the bottom of the plot window).

In ggplot2, how do we position the legend at the bottom of a plot window that has an increased bottom margin?

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `legend.position = "bottom"` adds the legend at the bottom of the plotting panel, not at the bottom of the entire plot image. It sounds like you want to increase the space between the x-axis and the legend instead. One option is to add a margin to the x-axis title text:

```r
p + 
  theme(plot.margin = margin(1, 1, 1, 1, unit = "cm"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(b = 3, unit = "cm")),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image: scatter plot]

- updated to use newer `margin` syntax instead of `unit`

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much indeed -- that's exactly what I wanted to do! Have a great day. :)